# ERROR! Converting Keras model to Tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have a simple classification model built with feature columns. I want to convert it to Tensorflow lite format. I'm using the Keras conversion code. But it gives the following error;

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

error message;

`InvalidArgumentError: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array.`

Why am I getting this error message?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model)` with `tf-nightly version`?

Comment: @Cansu Başer, Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: I am getting an error while downloading the tf-nightly version from colab. Is it okay since I am working with a dataset I created? Do I need to use compatible models for the tflite? Now I have created a model with the property columns.